# Is it possible write an 'ecv' class CV in another language?

Tags: languages, cv

I'm writing my CV. I use this template: `ecv` and 
there are two options `english` and `german`.

Is it possible write in Portuguese?

Comment: I think it's possible but you need to edit the `.sty` file or simply read it and use the `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`primitives for do that.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the `ecv` code isn't written in a way that encourages quick extensions to other languages (even though it could have been).  So the simplest way to use it with Portuguese is to pass the `[portuges]` (or `[brazilian]`) option to the class (which will then get passed on to `babel`), and then use `\renewcommand` to change all the titles.  I've done some of them here; some of the categories are quite weird to me, so I don't know what a good Portuguese translation would be.  Here's how a basic Portuguese CV would look like, however. I've used the code from the English template document supplied with the package documentation.

```
\documentclass[portuges]{ecv} % pass the [portuges] option to babel

% Dateiname: images/<portrait>.jpg
\ecvPortrait{portrait}
\ecvName{<Surname(s), Name>}
% Change these translations as needed
\renewcommand{\ecvPage}{P\'agina}
\renewcommand{\ecvTitle}{Curriculum Vitae}
\renewcommand{\ecvPerson}{Informa\c{c}\~ao pessoal}
\renewcommand{\ecvProfession}{Profiss\~ao}
\renewcommand{\ecvEducation}{Educa\c{c}\~ao}
\renewcommand{\ecvResearch}{Pesquisa}
\renewcommand{\ecvAwards}{Pr\^emios}
\renewcommand{\ecvPublications}{Publica\c{c}\~oes}
\renewcommand{\ecvScholarships}{Bolsas de estudo}
\renewcommand{\ecvJobs}{Empregos}
\renewcommand{\ecvLanguages}{L\'ingua(s)}
\renewcommand{\ecvLanguageTravels}{Language Travels}
\renewcommand{\ecvAbilities}{Abilities}
\renewcommand{\ecvConferences}{Confer\^encias}
\renewcommand{\ecvSpeeches}{Speeches}
\renewcommand{\ecvTrainig}{Training}
\renewcommand{\ecvAttachements}{Attachments}

\begin{document}
% The next line must come after the \begin{document} line
\selectlanguage{portuges} % tell babel to use Portuguese as the main language

\begin{ecv}
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Person
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvPerson}{\ecvPerson}}

\ecvEPR{Name}   {\textsc{<Name>}, <Surname(s)>}
\ecvEPR{Addresse}{<House number> <Street>\ecvNewLine
                 <City>, <Postcode>, <Country>}
\ecvEPR{Telephone}{<Area code>--<Telephone number>}
\ecvEPR{Fax}{<Area code>--<Faxnumber>}
\ecvEPR{E-Mail} {\ecvHyperEMail{<E-Mail>}}
\ecvEPR{Nationality}
                {<Nationality>}
\ecvEPR{Date of birth}
                {<Date of birth>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Profession
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvProfession}{\ecvProfession}}

% Chronologisch beginnend mit den juengsten Beschaeftigungen
\ecvEFR{Period}{<Year>--<Year>}
\ecvENR{Employer}
                {\ecvBold{<Company name>}\\
                 <House number><Street>, <City>, <Postcode>, <Country>}
%
\ecvEFR{Project <From> until <To>}
                {<Topic>}
\ecvENR{Position}{<Position held>}
\ecvENR{Main responsibilities}
                {<List of activities>}

%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Education
%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ecvBSec{\hypertarget{hypertarget:\ecvEducation}{\ecvEducation}}
\end{ecv}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]